# Selenide, dropdown, выбор первого значения в списке

Tags: css, css-selectors, selenide

Необходимо, чтобы в открывшимся списке выбиралось (кликалось) первое значение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="Select__menu css-26l3qy-menu" data-test-id="sellBasicInfoForm_make_temp_menu">
<div class="Select__menu-list css-11unzgr">
<div class="Select__option Select__option--is-focused css-1n7v3ny-option" id="react-select-2-option-0" tabindex="-1" data-test-id="sellBasicInfoForm_make_temp_option_MAKE_ABARTH" data-test-value="60"><div class="SelectField__SingleLabel-u2vi9c-8 fDpiAL">Abarth</div><
/div><div class="Select__option css-yt9ioa-option" id="react-select-2-option-1" tabindex="-1" data-test-id="sellBasicInfoForm_make_temp_option_MAKE_AC" data-test-value="115"><div class="SelectField__SingleLabel-u2vi9c-8 fDpiAL">AC</div></div><div class="Select__option css-yt9ioa-option" id="react-select-2-option-2" tabindex="-1" data-test-id="sellBasicInfoForm_make_temp_option_MAKE_ACURA" data-test-value="91"><div class="SelectField__SingleLabel-u2vi9c-8 fDpiAL">Acura</div></div>
<div class="Select__option css-yt9ioa-option" id="react-select-2-option-3" tabindex="-1" data-test-id="sellBasicInfoForm_make_temp_option_MAKE_AIXAM" data-test-value="104">
<div class="SelectField__SingleLabel-u2vi9c-8 fDpiAL">Aixam</div>
</div><div class="Select__option css-yt9ioa-option" id="react-select-2-option-4" tabindex="-1" data-test-id="sellBasicInfoForm_make_temp_option_MAKE_ALFA_ROMEO" data-test-value="16"><div class="SelectField__SingleLabel-u2vi9c-8 fDpiAL">Alfa Romeo</div>
</div><div class="Select__option css-yt9ioa-option" id="react-select-2-option-5" tabindex="-1" data-test-id="sellBasicInfoForm_make_temp_option_MAKE_ALPINA" data-test-value="39"><div class="SelectField__SingleLabel-u2vi9c-8 fDpiAL">ALPINA</div>
```

Пробовал:

```
 $("[data-test-id='sellBasicInfoForm_make_temp_menu']").selectOption(1);
```

Не работает этот способ

Вариант

```
$("[id='react-select-2-option-0']").click();
```

Тоже не годится, так как первым в списке может оказаться и Abarth и BMW и ZAZ

Comment: Зачем такое делать? Если есть специально придуманный вложенный список - `select`

Comment: потому что select для такой верстки не подходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(//*[@data-test-id='sellBasicInfoForm_make_temp_menu']//*[contains(@class, 'Select__option')])[1]
```